# Retrieve output/status of a variable from batch file to jenkins pipeline

Tags: batch-file, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying the retrieve the output/status of a variable available in bat to a jenkins pipeline by setting env variable initially as true.

My expectation is that based on the value of a variable assigned inside bat (i.e., `status=false`), next stage could not be executed since when expression is given in that stage:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment{
        STATUS='TRUE'
    }
    stages {
        stage('test1') {

            steps {
                bat '''set status=FALSE 
echo %status%'''   
                echo "$status" 
            }

        }
       stage('test2') {
            when{
               environment name: 'STATUS', value: 'TRUE' 
                }
            steps {
                input message: 'Push', ok: 'GO!!'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output which I am currently getting is **`o/p: false`** for bat execution and next step provides the output as true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `echo "$status"` is in pipeline, where as the environment `STATUS` changes are done on the node. AFAIK this won't get reflected in the pipeline itself.

What you could do is use `returnStdout: true` and maintain this variable state in the pipeline

```
def script = '''set status=FALSE 
    echo %status%'''   

def status = bat(script: script, returnStdout: true)
echo "$status"
```

Answer (score 4):

Following hakamairi answer above, `@echo off` should be added to the beginning of the script string, otherwise `returnStdout: true` will return the command prompt as well.

Also, adding `.trim()` by the end of the bat script (after its closing bracket) might prove useful if using the value of the assigned `status` variable somewhere else, where line break by the end is undesirable.